# Using Provider with with TickerProviderStateMixin: Where can I initialise my controller?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am just playing around with Flutter and I have run into a bit of an issue -> here is my repo: https://github.com/LuckyRon88/FlutterWebCV

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/motion_tab_bar/example to create a bottom Navigation bar as a Children of a stack. I will use this Bottom Navigation bar on multiple pages to change a widget on the screen so I refactored my code to have a BottomNavigation.dart.

I am using provider as my State management solution.

This is the TabBar https://github.com/LuckyRon88/FlutterWebCV/blob/master/lib/Components/TestTab.dart

which I want to use on https://github.com/LuckyRon88/FlutterWebCV/blob/master/lib/Screens/Education.dart but I need to be able to access the eduTabController (from TestTab.dart) from Education.dart to change some info on this very same page.

I already have a provider model https://github.com/LuckyRon88/FlutterWebCV/blob/master/lib/ProviderPack/PageController.dart but I am unsure how to give Provider the control of my eduTabController since I cannot initialise it anywhere but on the TestTab.dart itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `controller` in required in `MotionTabView` and not in `MotionTabBar` move the `_eduTabController` to `Education` class. Now define the function that is required on tab selection ,i.e, `onTabItemSelected` in `Education` class and pass it as an argument to `TestTab`.

This way you can avoid having the `_eduTabController` in `TestTab` and use it in `MotionTabView` which exist in `Education`.

Here is a rough implementation:

```
// convert Education to StatefulWidget
class Education extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EducationState createState() => _EducationState();
}

// Requires SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
class _EducationState extends State<Education> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final MotionTabController _eduTabController; // have your controller here

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize controller
    _eduTabController = MotionTabController(initialIndex: 1, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // dispose controller
    _eduTabController?.dispose();
  }

  // Extract your function from TestTab
  void onTabItemSelected(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _eduTabController.index = value;
    });
  },
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...

         Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           child: TestTab(
             // don't pass the controller
             onTabItemSelected: onTabItemSelected, // pass the function instead
           ), 
         ),

         MotionTabBarView(
           controller: _eduTabController,
           // ...
         ),

    //...
  }

}
```

```
// This should be a StatelessWidget (because it has no state)
// Change to StatefulWidget if your requirements change
class TestTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onTabItemSelected;

  TestTab({this.onTabItemSelected}); // receive your function here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MotionTabBar(
      // ...

      onTabItemSelected: onTabItemSelected, // use the function here

      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks!

I tried it but it goes into a weird loop that throws the error:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Each child must be laid out exactly once.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/danny/AndroidStudioProjects/roncv/lib/Screens/Education.dart:23:16
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I updated the repo https://github.com/LuckyRon88/FlutterWebCV

Any ideas?

Comment: I've made some changed, take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks! I will close the question I don't know why I Didn't think of this before.